# Как работает bittorent с серыми ip?

Tags: tcp-ip, p2p

Каким образом клиенты обмениваются данными по протоколу bittorent если ни у одного из них нету реального ip (серые ip)?

Comment: Погуглите "p2p за NAT сетями".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак не обмениваются, обмениваются с теми у кого белый адрес есть. Пользователей с белыми IP сейчас много, у большинства они динамические, но p2p это не помеха.

Есть какие-то механизмы обхода NATа, но на сколько мне известно в bittorrent они не используются.

*Обновление*

Реутеры (ведь подразумеваются SOHO-роутеры?) позволяют решать проблему обхода своих собственных NAT-ов по сути предоставляя хостам за собой простую ручку для настройки проброса портов (технология называется UPnP). С этим всё хорошо, более менее, но что-бы от этого был какой-то прок (кроме возможности работы с локальными пирами) нужно что-бы сам SOHO-роутер не находился за NAT-ом

Comment: >Есть какие-то механизмы обхода NATа
Сейчас роутеры пытаются решать эту проблему.. как доживем до ipv6 так и будет свобода.

Comment: Реутеры (ведь подразумеваются SOHO-роутеры?) позволяют решать проблему обхода своих собственных NAT-ов по сути предоставляя хостам за собой простую ручку для настройки проброса портов (технология называется UPnP). С этим всё хорошо, более менее, но что-бы от этого был какой-то прок (кроме возможности работы с локальными пирами) нужно что-бы сам SOHO-роутер не находился за NAT-ом